# extracting values starting at a specific character string and up until a certain character string

Tags: .net, regex

Given the following multiline string:

```
WHERE ([EXTENT1].[MY_ID] IN (151,152,214,218,931,932,933,1067,1412,1414,13807,14347,14349,14446)) AND ([EXTENT1].[MY_OTHER_ID] IN (14264, 14335, 14385, 14398, 14603, 14650, 15164, 15374)) AND ([EXTENT2].[PERSON_ID] IN (28,933,14446,179,152,14349,14347,933,130,218,933,1067,931,151,214,152,933,145,931,145,5809,14347,14349,14349,1414,142,1412,179,152,14347,152,90,13807,932,931))
    )  AS [FILTER1]
    GROUP BY [K1], [K2]
)  AS [GROUPBY1]
```

I want to extract the parenthesized values of the IN clause for [MY_ID].  I can use the following regex `(?<=\.\[MY_ID\].*IN.*\().*` to truncate off the first portion of the string and return:

```
 151,152,214,218,931,932,933,1067,1412,1414,13807,14347,14349,14446)) AND ([EXTENT1].[MY_OTHER_ID] IN (14264, 14335, 14385, 14398, 14603, 14650, 15164, 15374)) AND ([EXTENT2].[PERSON_ID] IN (28,933,14446,179,152,14349,14347,933,130,218,933,1067,931,151,214,152,933,145,931,145,5809,14347,14349,14349,1414,142,1412,179,152,14347,152,90,13807,932,931))
```

But I can't figure out how to have it stop at the first closing ) of the in clause.

What I am after is: `151,152,214,218,931,932,933,1067,1412,1414,13807,14347,14349,14446`

The regex will eventually be used in with the .NET regex engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the fact that .NET regex supports *repeated groups*, you can use

```
\.\[MY_ID]\s*IN\s*\(((?:,?(\d+))+)
```

and grab either the Group 1  value (that will be `151,152,214,218,931,932,933,1067,1412,1414,13807,14347,14349,14446`) or all the captures from the Group 2 capture collection as an array/list.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c.%5c%5bMY_ID%5d%5cs*IN%5cs*%5c(((%3f%3a%2c%3f(%5cd%2b))%2b)&i=%24str+%3d+%22WHERE+(%5bEXTENT1%5d.%5bMY_ID%5d+IN+(151%2c152%2c214%2c218%2c931%2c932%2c933%2c1067%2c1412%2c1414%2c13807%2c14347%2c14349%2c14446))+AND+(%5bEXTENT1%5d.%5bMY_OTHER_ID%5d+IN+(14264%2c+14335%2c+14385%2c+14398%2c+14603%2c+14650%2c+15164%2c+15374))+AND+(%5bEXTENT2%5d.%5bPERSON_ID%5d+IN+(28%2c933%2c14446%2c179%2c152%2c14349%2c14347%2c933%2c130%2c218%2c933%2c1067%2c931%2c151%2c214%2c152%2c933%2c145%2c931%2c145%2c5809%2c14347%2c14349%2c14349%2c1414%2c142%2c1412%2c179%2c152%2c14347%2c152%2c90%2c13807%2c932%2c931))%5cn++++)++AS+%5bFILTER1%5d%5cn++++GROUP+BY+%5bK1%5d%2c+%5bK2%5d%5cn)++AS+%5bGROUPBY1%5d%22%3b+%0d%0a+)

Explanation:

- `\.\[MY_ID]` - a literal `.[MY_ID]`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace
- `IN\s*` - `IN` word followed with 0+ whitespace
- `\(` - opening literal `(`
- `((?:,?(\d+))+)` - Group 1 capturing 1+ sequences of:

  - `,?` - one or zero comma
  - `(\d+)` - Group 2 capturing 1+ digits.

And here is a [C# demo](http://ideone.com/wzhoPv):

```
var s = "WHERE ([EXTENT1].[MY_ID] IN (151,152,214,218,931,932,933,1067,1412,1414,13807,14347,14349,14446)) AND ([EXTENT1].[MY_OTHER_ID] IN (14264, 14335, 14385, 14398, 14603, 14650, 15164, 15374)) AND ([EXTENT2].[PERSON_ID] IN (28,933,14446,179,152,14349,14347,933,130,218,933,1067,931,151,214,152,933,145,931,145,5809,14347,14349,14349,1414,142,1412,179,152,14347,152,90,13807,932,931))\n    )  AS [FILTER1]\n    GROUP BY [K1], [K2]\n)  AS [GROUPBY1]"; 
var pattern = @"\.\[MY_ID]\s*IN\s*\(((?:,?(\d+))+)";
var matches = Regex.Matches(s, pattern);
var res1 = matches
                .Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Groups[2].Captures) // Get a list of ind. numbers
                .ToList();
var res2 = matches
                .Cast<Match>().Select(p => p.Groups[1].Value) // Get the whole substring
                .ToList();
 foreach (var coll in res1)
    foreach (var v in coll)
        Console.WriteLine(v);
 Console.WriteLine("Ex. 2");
    foreach (var v2 in res2)
        Console.WriteLine(v2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with following regex.

**Regex:** `(?<=\[MY_ID\] IN \()[^)]*`

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=\[MY_ID\] IN \()` will `look behind` for `[MY_ID] IN (`
- `[^)]*` will **match** everything till a `)` is met, which marks the close of parenthesis.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lO4uJ3/4)**

Comment: This is also an acceptable answer, but Wiktor's had the extra .NET component which got me the direct list of values, that I was ultimately after.